# A square grid path problem proof

Tags: combinatorics

Let n be a positive integer. Consider all possible ways of arranging n pairs of parentheses “(” and “)” in a row. We want to arrange them in a way that it is possible to pair up the left parentheses with the right parenthesis so that “(” is to the left of “)”. Let An be the set of all such arrangements with n pairs of parentheses. There are 5 elements in A3, as shown below.
((())) (()()) (())() ()(()) ()()()

On an n × n grid, we consider paths travelling along the grid lines from the SW corner to the NE corner of the grid with the conditions that we only travel in the N or E direction, and we never travel above the x = y line. Let Bn be the set of all such paths in an n × n grid. There are 5 elements in B3

Now how do I prove this using a bijection(|An| = |Bn|)?

Comment: Hint: choose a path and write it out as a sequence of letters (N and E). How many such sequences can you make?

Comment: Are you sure ${2n \choose n}$ is correct? That seems to count the paths without the "below the diagonal" restriction. When $n=1$, for example, it says there are $2$ paths, but there should only be $1$. (I assume that by "$n \times n$ grid" you mean $n$ squares by $n$ squares, for $n+1$ grid points on each side.)

Comment: @GregoryJ.Puleo Yes you are right I was mistaken, I have edited the question. This is what I am trying to solve. Please have a look

Comment: @Théophile Thanks for the idea, how can I use this NE sequence of letters to find an bijection?

Comment: Just label any legal move on you grid using a string consists of alphabet $E$ and $N$ and then translate every $E$ to "(" and every $N$ to ")".  You should find the wiki page for [Catalan number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number) relevant and useful.

Comment: @achillehui Yes I did that, but I am not sure how to formalize it

Comment: What you really need is a more precise/concrete definition of the predicate `"(" is to the left of ")"` for strings formed using "(" and ")". If you remove that restriction from $A_n$ and the constraint  `never travel above the x = y line` from $B_n$, there is already a bijection between the extended $A_n$ and $B_n$. If you can show under this bijection,  $A_n$ get mapped onto $B_n$, then you are done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $a_0 = (0,0)$ be the SW corner and $a_{2n} = (n,n)$ the NW corner.  Suppose a path from $a_0$ to $a_{2n}$ does go above the diagonal.  Say the first time it does so is at $a_j = (k, k+1)$ (where we must have $j = 2k+1$).
Reflect the part of the path from $a_0$ to $a_j$ across the line $y=x+1$, and
you have a path (still consisting of N and E moves) from $(-1,1)$ to $(n,n)$.  Conversely, given any path from $(-1,1)$ to $(n,n)$, it must at some point hit the line $y=x+1$, and if you reflect the part of the path up to that point you get a path from $(0,0)$ to $(n,n)$ that goes above the diagonal.  We conclude that the number of paths from $a_0$ to $a_{2n}$ that go above the diagonal is the same as the number of all paths from $(-1,1)$ to $a_{2n}$, which is $2n \choose n+1$ (because there are $2n$ steps, of which $n+1$ are E and $n-1$ N).  The total number of paths from $a_0$ to $a_{2n}$ is $2n \choose n$.  So the number of paths that don't cross the diagonal is
${2n \choose n} - {2n \choose n+1}$.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer but can you tell me how to prove the required statement |An| = |Bn| using a bijection